# Problems with struct

Tags: c++

so i was having two types of issues from my code... the general forms are:

"left of ... must have class/struct/union " :

```
                      doc.id[j] = NULL;
                      doc.ISBN[j] = NULL;
                      doc.title[j] = NULL;
                      doc.year[j] = NULL;
```

and " 'doc' uses undefined struct 'main::m_doc'"

```
struct m_doc doc;
```

while the struct m_doc doc is included in the top of each function .

here is my struct :

```
struct m_doc{

    char id[30];
    int ISBN[30];
    char title[50];
    char author[50];
    int year[30];
};
```

my fist function :

```
void menudoc()
{   struct m_doc doc;
    int c = 0, a = 0, b;
    cout << "1. Them tai lieu moi" << endl;
    cout << "2. Xoa tai lieu" << endl;
    cout << "3. Bao cao theo nam xuat ban" << endl;
    cout << "0. Tro lai menu truoc" << endl;
    cout << "Ban chon:";
    cin >> b;
    switch (b)
    {
    case 1:
    {
              for (int i = 0;; i++)
              {
                  if (doc.id[i] == NULL && doc.ISBN[i] == NULL && doc.title[i] == NULL && doc.author[i] == NULL && doc.year[i] == NULL)
                  {
                      i = c; break;
                  }
                  else continue;
              }
              cin >> doc.author[c] ;
              cin >> doc.id[c] ;
              cin >> doc.ISBN[c] ;
              cin >> doc.title[c];
              cin >> doc.year[c];
              for (int i = 0;; i++){
                  for (int j = 1;; j++){
                      if (doc.id[i] == doc.id[j]){
                          doc.author[j] = NULL;
                          doc.id[j] = NULL;
                          doc.ISBN[j] = NULL;
                          doc.title[j] = NULL;
                          doc.year[j] = NULL;
                      }
                      if (doc.year[i]<1000 || doc.year[i]>9999){
                          doc.author[i] = NULL;
                          doc.id[i] = NULL;
                          doc.ISBN[i] = NULL;
                          doc.title[i] = NULL;
                          doc.year[i] = NULL;
                      }
                  }
              }
              break;
    }


    case 2:
    {
              int x;
    char docid[50];
    cout << "IDDOC: ";
    cin >> docid[50];
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0;; i++){
        if (docid[50] == doc.id[i]) {
            doc.author[i] = NULL;
            doc.id[i] = NULL;
            doc.ISBN[i] = NULL;
            doc.title[i] = NULL;
            doc.year[i] = NULL;
            x++;
        }

    }
    if (x == 0) cout << "IDDOC khong ton tai." << endl;
    break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
              int yeardoc[50];
    cin >> yeardoc[50];
    for (int i = 0;; i++){
        if (yeardoc[50] == doc.year[i])
            write_output(i, "report.scv");

    }
    break;
    }
    case 0:
    {
              menubegin();
              break;
    }
        menudoc();
    }
```

}

my second function :

```
int write_output(int i, char* filename){
    ios::out;
    struct m_doc doc;
    // open file for output
    ofstream fout(filename);
    char * k, *h;
    k = strchr(doc.title, ',');
    h = strchr(doc.author, ',');
    if (k != 0 && h != 0)fout << doc.id[i] << "\n" << doc.ISBN[i] << "\n" << '"' << doc.title[i] << '"' << "\n" << '"' << doc.author[i] << '"' << "\n" << doc.year[i] << endl;
    if (k != 0) fout << doc.id[i] << "\n" << doc.ISBN[i] << "\n" << '"' << doc.title[i] << '"' << "\n" << doc.author[i] << "\n" << doc.year[i] << endl;
    if (h != 0)fout << doc.id[i] << "\n" << doc.ISBN[i] << "\n" << doc.title[i] << "\n" << '"' << doc.author[i] << '"' << "\n" << doc.year[i] << endl;
    // write informations
    if (k == 0 && h == 0)fout << doc.id[i] << "\n" << doc.ISBN[i] << "\n" << doc.title[i] << "\n" << doc.author[i] << "\n" << doc.year[i] << endl;

    // close file
    fout.close();


    return 0;
}
```

anybody im asked said that it was something about scope but none of them know the problem since everything looks fine... please help me , every help is much appreciated :)

Comment: indentation ? error lines ?

Comment: Surely you can do a better job of providing the error specifics... since you want people to help with the error you're receiving. No?

Comment: You post the second function **twice**.

Comment: sorry for the childish display :) editted :D

Comment: The last entry in the `switch` statement doesn't have a corresponding `case`. If the issue is in `main()`, why are you looking elsewhere?

Comment: ahh that menudoc is actually done after the switch(b) is finished so as to comeback to previous screen after the actions are done :D

Comment: please help me upvote , this thread has become so low nobody want to read it while i dont want to create another thread and trash the site :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a guess that you are confused about when to use *forward declarations* and when to *include* the structure definition.  Here are some guidelines.

**Forward Declaration**
A forward declaration of a structure is of the form:

```
struct m_doc doc;
```

This form is used to resolve definitions, any pointer or reference that refers to the symbol `doc`.  Usually this is placed in a header file before other structure or function declarations to reduce the number of `#include` files.

**Structure Definition**
You need to have the structure definition present before any code that:

1. Creates an instance of the structure,
2. Or before anything that refers to the details of the structure
   (members & methods).

**Placing structures in `#include` files**
Rather than typing the structure everywhere it is used, a convenient practice is to place it in a header file, usually ".h" for C language structures and ".hpp" or ".hh" for C++ classes and structures.  So when you have a function in a source file that references the structure (or creates an instance of the structure), include the file with the definition before it is used by the function.

Most compilers issue the error

```
"left of ... must have class/struct/union "
```

when it can't find the definition or declaration of the structure.